# Packery with Bootstrap Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, packery

I'm trying to use **Packery** to build a dashboard with draggable widgets (using **Draggabilly** for dragging).  The widgets have their width determined by **Bootstrap** classes, as to be responsive over various screen sizes.  I'm also using **jQuery** to grab elements and stuff.

## [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/sambostock/pen/xwPvNM)

#### HTML Snippet

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row' id='dashboard-root'>
    <div class='dashboard-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
      Some content</br></br>
    </div>
    <div class='dashboard-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
      Some other content<br>
    </div>
    <div class='dashboard-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
      Even more content<br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class='dashboard-item col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6'>
    Some wide content is super wide, even wider than you even thought possible, like this is so crazy wide you wouldn't believe it.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS Snippet

```
.dashboard-item{
  border-style: solid ;
}

.container{
  border-style: dashed ;
}
```

#### JavaScript Snippet

```
var $root = $('#dashboard-root') ;

$root.packery({
  itemSelector: '.dashboard-item'
});

$root.find('.dashboard-item').each(function(i, itemElem){
  var draggie = new Draggabilly(itemElem) ;
  $root.packery('bindDraggabillyEvents', draggie);
});
```

As it stands, the widgets are draggable, but **I need them to snap to some sort of grid**.  Currently, they can be placed anywhere, which makes positioning weird.

I'm trying to figure out how to make them snap to Bootstrap's grid columns.  Ideally, I'd want the elements to snap to the nearest col-*-1, I think.  Not sure what to do with the height though.

I tried playing with setting the [columnWidth](http://packery.metafizzy.co/options.html#columnwidth) to a selector for a dummy element, but I couldn't get it to work.